# Can I set a filter condition on Visual Studio 2013's Watch Window

Tags: filter, visual-studio-2013, fortran, conditional-statements, watch

My program has very large matrices but most of the elements tend to be zero. Is there a way to set in the watch window something like the following for a 50x10000x2 matrix variable called tau_bcst:

```
Name                    Value
tau_bcst.ge.0           {...}
```

Such that in watch, it will only show the elements greater than zero. Something like the following:

```
Name                    Value
tau_bcst(1,4,1)         3
tau_bcst(10,2000,1)     3
tau_bcst(11,2000,1)     3
tau_bcst(49,2910,2)     3
tau_bcst(21,8930,2)     3
```

I know it can take some mathematical equations and calculate a value with the variables, so I am wondering if it can do this as well. I tried several ways but it doesn't seem to work.

I would gladly use a simple filter code to check the variable (return 1 if the values are non-zero, for example), except that I have many variables that I want to check at potentially multiple points in the code against another run of the code in another Visual Studio window so that won't be very efficient.

Comment: I don't recall vs2013 very well, but if you can pass an expression to the watch list, you could pass something like `pack(tau_bcst, mask=tau_bcst >= 0)`. If you need the original indices of the packed elements, it would be a little trickier, but a simple auxiliary function would do that.

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues yeah that is what I thought. I tried your suggestion but it says syntax error. If my variable exists in a separate module, which means I need to call it with module::tau_bcst, it shouldn't matter right?